# Bootstrap doesn't wrap the columns properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on rebuilding and old SVG based semicircle menu with Bootstrap and I want to have a layout like this:

....[3+3+3+3]....
[12][..6+6..][12]
[12][3+6+3][12]

I have an upper-mid part with a 6 column width and 4 equal inner items, down I have a left and right part with 3 column width and a mid part with 6 column between them. My problem is the left-mid-righ parts don't wrap under the upper-mid part. Bootstrap just squeezes them into one single row...Should it put the items more than 12 columns under it?

Inside the parts the subparts wrap perfectly or when I comment out the left-mid-right part the upper-mid is positioned perfectly.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="semicircle-menu col-sm-12 hidden-xs">
            <div class="upper-mid col-sm-6 center-block">
                <div class="menu-item manage-dashboards col-sm-3">Manage Dashboards</div>
                <div class="menu-item add-new-dashboard col-sm-3">Add New Dashboard</div>
                <div class="menu-item manage-alerts col-sm-3">Manage Alerts</div>
                <div class="menu-item add-new-alert col-sm-3">Add New Alert</div>
            </div>
            <div class="left col-sm-3">
                <div class="menu-item-sub add-new-dataset col-sm-12">Add New Dataset</div>
                <div class="menu-item-sub manage-datasets col-sm-12">Manage Datasets</div>
                <div class="menu-item-sub data-sources col-sm-12">Data Sources</div>
            </div>
            <div class="mid col-sm-6">
                <div class="menu-item dashboards col-sm-6">Dashboards</div>
                <div class="menu-item alerts col-sm-6">Alerts</div>
                <div class="menu-item master-data col-sm-3">Master Data</div>
                <div class="indicator col-sm-6">DataIQ</div>
                <div class="menu-item maintenance col-sm-3">Maintenance</div>
            </div>
            <div class="right col-sm-3">
                <div class="menu-item-sub users col-sm-12">Users</div>
                <div class="menu-item-sub user-groups col-sm-12">User Groups</div>
                <div class="menu-item-sub settings col-sm-12">Settings</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The solution was putting a row inside the semicircle-menu element and put 1-1 blank placeholder element with 3 column width around the upper-mid element and define their height etc. properties in css.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to define row when you have defined col-sm-12 each row consist of 12 grid. So to define grids inside a grid you need to define row first and divide those 12 grids accordingly. Here i have updated your code you forgot to add row inside grid. There cannot be 18 grid in one row. Else you have to customize your bootstrap grid.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="semicircle-menu col-sm-12 hidden-xs">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="upper-mid col-sm-6 center-block">
            <div class="menu-item manage-dashboards col-sm-3">Manage Dashboards</div>
            <div class="menu-item add-new-dashboard col-sm-3">Add New Dashboard</div>
            <div class="menu-item manage-alerts col-sm-3">Manage Alerts</div>
            <div class="menu-item add-new-alert col-sm-3">Add New Alert</div>
        </div>
        <div class="left col-sm-3">
            <div class="menu-item-sub add-new-dataset col-sm-12">Add New Dataset</div>
            <div class="menu-item-sub manage-datasets col-sm-12">Manage Datasets</div>
            <div class="menu-item-sub data-sources col-sm-12">Data Sources</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="mid col-sm-6">
            <div class="menu-item dashboards col-sm-6">Dashboards</div>
            <div class="menu-item alerts col-sm-6">Alerts</div>
            <div class="menu-item master-data col-sm-3">Master Data</div>
            <div class="indicator col-sm-6">DataIQ</div>
            <div class="menu-item maintenance col-sm-3">Maintenance</div>
        </div>
        <div class="right col-sm-3">
            <div class="menu-item-sub users col-sm-12">Users</div>
            <div class="menu-item-sub user-groups col-sm-12">User Groups</div>
            <div class="menu-item-sub settings col-sm-12">Settings</div>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes what you have mentioned. Exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="semicircle-menu col-sm-12 hidden-xs text-center">
            <div class="row upper-mid">
                <div class="col-sm-3">Manage Dashboards</div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">Add New Dashboard</div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">Manage Alerts</div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">Add New Alert</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 left">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">Add New Dataset</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">Manage Dataset</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">Data Sources</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 mid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">Dashboards</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">Alerts</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">Master Data</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">DataIQ</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">Maintenance</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 right">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">Users</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">User Groups</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">Settings</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, so mine was a bit close to your needs